# Imported variables do not overwrite existing ones

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program repeat many times. For that, I need to overwrite some imported variables because they get changed in the course of the program.

The code in `main.py`:

```
while True:
    ...
    from vars import field, game, screen, ai
    ...
```

In `vars.py` the variables `field`, `game`, `screen` and `ai` get defined.
The first time the program runs it works fine, however the next time the variables don't change and the program breaks.
How do I fix this?

Comment: import them before you loop

Comment: first solution: don't overwrite them if you need the original values. Keep them by themselves, and work with copies. Remember that you're changing the original variables, not copies after importing them.

Comment: An import statement will only be executed if it hasn't already been executed during the current session.

Comment: Beside the point, but `vars` is the name of a builtin, so not a good name for a module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've already imported them in the first iteration, you won't be able to reimport them, as they are [already in `sys.modules`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#finders-and-loaders).

You could [reload](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload) the module, reimporting the variables, but I would not recommend that.

Instead, copy the variables and re-assign them as needed.

```
from vars import field, game, screen, ai

from copy import copy, deepycopy

while True:
    ...
    my_field = copy(field)  # Use deepcopy instead if needed
    my_game = copy(game)
    my_screen = copy(screen)
    my_ai = copy(ai)
    ...
```

With primitives and immutable types you can simply do `my_x = x`.

The [`copy` docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/copy.html) will aiding in deciding whether you should use copy or deepcopy.

Comment: You will be able to "reimport" them as attempted in this question - the variable will be restored to the original reference from when it was imported. But since the asker isn't copying the content, they're changing the original reference - not getting a fresh copy. `import math, math = 'abc123', import math` restores `math` as a reference to the `math` module.

Comment: @MatsLindh Definitely, they would have to use `import vars` and refer to the variables as `vars.x`. I'm not aware of a way to make reloading work with `from vars import x`.

Comment: Neither of them would reload, but `from vars import x` will restore the reference to the variable located inside `x` again at least (in the same manner as `import foo` restores `foo`).

Comment: Now that it copies the imported variables, I have a problem: When `ai` is loaded, it reads the content of `wins.txt` which is saved in a variable. This file is changed throughout the game so when it copies `ai` in the next round, the new content of `wins.txt` isn't displayed. Dou you have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: @R. B. That would be worth asking a new question after a bit of research (I'd advise you to try re-reading the file but without the code I can't say what's happening)

Answer (score 0):

Only import once, then loop:

```
from vars import ai, field, game, screen

while True:
    local_ai = ai
    local_field = field
    local_game = game
    local_screen = screen
```